# Powershell to create Excel with select highlighting

Tags: excel, powershell

I am trying to create PowerShell that will highlight first 5 columns of the first row.

I tried this

```
$excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$excel.Rows.Item("1:5").Interior.ColorIndex = 5
```

Among other variations in Item() and got strange output, i.e.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $true
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.add()
$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet
$sheet.Range("A1:F1").interior.colorindex = 5
```